# передача параметров о структуре которых обрабатывающей функции ничего не известно

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, параметры

Есть универсальная функция `start`, которая на вход принимает указатель на неизвестную функцию, которая должна быть выполнена и массив неизвестных параметров, один из которых должен быть передан этой функции на вход, т.е.:

```
typedef void(*func_t)(void*);
```

Эта универсальная функция (или метод некоторого класса) ничего о полученной функции или массиве данных ничего не знает, кроме одного - какой именно элемент массива надо передать полученной функции на вход.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать с помощью 2 параметров, т.е.:

```
void MyFunc(void* params)
{
    CMyParams* data = (CMyParams*)params;

    // основной код
}

CMyParams* myAllData = new CMyParams[1000];

start(MyFunc, myAllData);
```

где

```
void start(func_t func, void* data)
{
    const int index = 123; // единственный параметр о котором знает функция start

    func(&data[index]);
}
```

И вот с таким способом передачи параметров у меня и возникает проблема, а голова что-то не варит. Наверное должно всплыть `void**`, но не улавливают :(

Я решил эту проблему тем, что в функцию `func_t` передаю третьим параметром `index`, но это чистый костыль. **А как обойтись без него?**

И хочется, чтобы функция `start` вообще не знала ничего о функции и данных, которые она получает - не ее это дело.

**P.S.**

Дело в том, что функция `start` кроме `index`, знает еще и о размере передаваемого массива `amount` и должна не просто вызвать функцию, а вызвать функцию с разными параметрами (т.е. в цикле)

```
for (index = 0; index < amount; index++)
{
     func(&data[index]);
}
```

Comment: Ну передавайте в `start` сразу указатель на 123-й объект.

Comment: Вы специально все усложняете? .. Просто же можно вызвать  MyFunc(&myAllData[123]).  И функция   start абсолютно не нужна. А вместо void*   определите функцию с аргументом CMyParams*.   Передать функции указатель на массив,  следить за тем, что этот массив имел больше123 элементов, а потом следить за тем, чтобы массив удалялся... Не  для  нашего века такой подход

Comment: Ой - я забыл написать важную вещь - дело в том, что функция `start` кроме `index`, знает еще и о размере передаваемого массива `amount` и должна не просто вызвать функцию, а вызвать функцию с разными параметрами (т.е. в цикле)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что сделать это не представляется возможным.

В своём примере вы просите обратиться к элементу массива data (типа void *)  с определённым индексом:

```
for (index = 0; index < amount; index++)
{
     func(&data[index]);
}
```

Но компилятор не может этого сделать по одной простой причине. 
Например, обращаясь к некоему mas[4], компилятор должен знать, куда нужно переместиться (на какое число байт от начала массива), выполняя операцию mas[4]. 
Если mas объявлен как (в качестве примера) int mas[10], компилятору известен тип данных, он может высчитать размер одного элемента и может подвинуться на нужное число элементов.

Адрес mas[4] равен адресу начала массива mas + sizeof(int)*4, где инфу про int он берёт из объявления.

К сожалению, в случаеcс void * компилятор не может получить размер элемента данных.